# Enum is attempting to initialize itself via a non-existant public initializer

Tags: java, intellij-idea, enums, initialization

I have an Enum, Layout. I defined some of the members(don't remember the correct term for this), using a private initializer. For some reason, it's claiming 'Layout is abstract; cannot be instantiated'(Intellij Idea). The private initializer I declared, is showing a warning saying it's never used. Code:

```
public static enum Layout {
    CHARGE("Charge", false, false),

    FESS("Fess", true, true),

    PALE("Pale", true, true),

    QUARTERLY("Quarterly", true, false),

    PARTY_PER_PALE("Party per pale", true, false),

    BORDURE("Bordure", true, false),

    PARTY_PER_BEND_SINISTER("Party per bend sinister", true, false),

    SCARPE("Scarpe", true, false),

    THREE("Three", false, false),

    COUNTERCHARGED("Countercharged", false, false);

    public final String name;
    public final boolean hasSecondary;
    public final boolean chargeInSecondary;

    public abstract String blazon(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms);

    public abstract void draw(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms, MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2, double paramDouble3);

    public abstract void drawLayout(MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2);

    private Layout(String name, boolean hasSecondary, boolean chargeInSecondary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hasSecondary = hasSecondary;
        this.chargeInSecondary = chargeInSecondary;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you think would happen, if you add abstract methods to a enum and don't override them for each enum constant?

Comment: I am seeing compilation errors for this code since the abstract methods are not over ridden.

Comment: fabian is right, your enum values need to override all the abstract methods in the enum. also remove that static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract objects can't be initialized. Since enum constants are initialized however, they have to be non-abstract. Therefore all methods have to be implemented.

You have 2 options:

1. Remove the abstract methods
2. Implement the abstract methods for every enum constant:

   ```
   public enum Layout {
       CHARGE("Charge", false, false) {

           @Override
           public String blazon(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms) {
               // ...
           }

           @Override
           public void draw(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms, MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2, double paramDouble3) {
               // ...
           }

           @Override
           public void drawLayout(MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2) {
               // ...
           }

       },

       FESS("Fess", true, true) {

          @Override
          public String blazon(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms) {
              // ...
          }

          @Override
          public void draw(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms, MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2, double paramDouble3) {
               // ...
          }

          @Override
          public void drawLayout(MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2) {
              // ...
          }

       }

       /*
        rest of the constants, each implementing the methods
        */ ;

       public final String name;
       public final boolean hasSecondary;
       public final boolean chargeInSecondary;

       public abstract String blazon(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms);

       public abstract void draw(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms, MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2, double paramDouble3);

       public abstract void drawLayout(MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2);

       private Layout(String name, boolean hasSecondary, boolean chargeInSecondary) {
           this.name = name;
           this.hasSecondary = hasSecondary;
           this.chargeInSecondary = chargeInSecondary;
       }
   }
   ```

---

The `static` keyword also may not belong there, depending on where the enum is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Since you declared `abstract` methods in your `enum` it's considered to be `abstract` (like an abstract class) which is why you can't instantiate it. You also can't declare it static!

fixed enum:

```
public enum Layout {
    CHARGE("Charge", false, false),

    FESS("Fess", true, true),

    PALE("Pale", true, true),

    QUARTERLY("Quarterly", true, false),

    PARTY_PER_PALE("Party per pale", true, false),

    BORDURE("Bordure", true, false),

    PARTY_PER_BEND_SINISTER("Party per bend sinister", true, false),

    SCARPE("Scarpe", true, false),

    THREE("Three", false, false),

    COUNTERCHARGED("Countercharged", false, false);

    public final String name;
    public final boolean hasSecondary;
    public final boolean chargeInSecondary;

    private Layout(String name, boolean hasSecondary, boolean chargeInSecondary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.hasSecondary = hasSecondary;
        this.chargeInSecondary = chargeInSecondary;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems: 1) You can't have an enum defined as `static`. They effectively already are. 2) You can't include abstract methods in an enum. You must fully define all methods.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep the abstract methods out of the Enum

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    public static enum Layout {
        CHARGE("Charge", false, false),

        FESS("Fess", true, true),

        PALE("Pale", true, true),

        QUARTERLY("Quarterly", true, false),

        PARTY_PER_PALE("Party per pale", true, false),

        BORDURE("Bordure", true, false),

        PARTY_PER_BEND_SINISTER("Party per bend sinister", true, false),

        SCARPE("Scarpe", true, false),

        THREE("Three", false, false),

        COUNTERCHARGED("Countercharged", false, false);

        public final String name;
        public final boolean hasSecondary;
        public final boolean chargeInSecondary;

        private Layout(String name, boolean hasSecondary, boolean chargeInSecondary) {
            this.name = name;
            this.hasSecondary = hasSecondary;
            this.chargeInSecondary = chargeInSecondary;
        }
    }

     public abstract String blazon(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms);

     public abstract void draw(CoatOfArms paramCoatOfArms, MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2, double paramDouble3);

     public abstract void drawLayout(MyDraw paramMyDraw, double paramDouble1, double paramDouble2);

}
```